# How can I upload large (30Mb) files in a ASP.NET application ? (VB) I've tried raising MaxRequestLength, but no luck

Tags: .net, asp.net, upload, size, file-upload

How can I upload large (30Mb) files in a ASP.NET application ? (VB) I've tried raising MaxRequestLength, but no luck...

I'm using the FileUpload control, I already googled this issue a bit, and people seem to solve it by raising MaxrequestLenght on the web.config file.
I did that, and it didn't work.

I also raised it on the code, and still it doesn't work, the page doesn't even do postback.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, solved it, I had the maxrequestlenght on the wrong site.
Shame on me.
Now off to see if 20 Mbs is too much for the server to handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this in your web.config

```
  <system.web>
     <httpRuntime executionTimeout="360" maxRequestLength="100000" />
```

That enables a 360 second timeout and 100,000 Kb of upload data at a time.

If that doesn't work, run this command on your IIS server. (replace [IISWebsitename])

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>appcmd set config "[IISWebsitename]" -section:requestFiltering -requestLimits.maxAllowedContentLength:100000000 -commitpath:apphost
```

That enables 100,000,000 bytes of upload data at a time.